# Neo4j vs (Neo4j + Postgres)

Tags: database, postgresql, graph, neo4j, rdbms

I am developing an recommendation engine and was thinking of saving actual data (email, name, password, etc) in `Postgres` and saving relationship in `Neo4j`. But was wondering if this gives any advantage over storing everything in `Neo4j`. Will storing everything in `Neo4j` affect its performance and scalability?

Comment: How on earth could anyone tell without knowing schema details, data quantities, usage patterns, hardware available etc? There are trade-offs to be made but you'll need to quantify them.

Answer (score 1):

I read that you are developing a recommender engine on top of neo4j.
Could you have a look to Reco4J, it is an open source recommendation framework based on graph database,
that has an implementation fro Neo4J.

Have a look and let me know if you could be interested into it, since there we are resolving scalability issue with several of our customers.

Cheers,
Alessandro

Answer (score 1):

Yes,Storing everything in Neo4j(node's or relationship's propertites) will affect its performance badly.

In our project,we use neo4j + mongoDB.But there are some properties must be stored in neo4j for some reason.I found that when you try to search something in neo4j,the number of properties that you want to return does matters to its performance.

Just return the node's id(or relationship id) will be the best,then some properties,the whole node or relationship will be the last choice.

Forgive my poor English!!